# Reconfigure Bitcoin Core to allow Wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoin-cli

I installed and configured a testnet node but I forgot to install sqlite so all wallet-related commands do not work... Is there a way to fix that without having to setup a whole new node? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just recompile with the wallet enabled, and restart.

It won't need to redownload things, as the bulk of the work in setting up a node is synchronizing with the network. The resulting database is the same whether there are wallets or not.

Comment: So just install sqlite and then run `make` && `make run` again? Or also `configure` ?

Comment: Also configure.